# Google Cloud Platform - Server running PHP 7.3x however Wordpress says 7.0x - How do I get WP to run on 7.3x?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I'm having an issue. I've installed 7.3x on the server - However, my WP says it's running on 7.0x

Using GCP VM Click-to-deploy WP - Standard VM type.

How do I get WordPress to use the updated PHP?

See Screens

[Server SSH PHP Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgCYO.png) - [Wordpress PHP Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZoaq.png)

Comment: Can you also share the webserver configuration please.

Comment: What information would you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

You have two option Web publishing platform for building multiple blogs and websites from GCP Marketplace as follow:

WordPress Multisite (Google Click to Deploy)
Estimated costs: $24.75/month

```
Apache 2.4.25
Google-Fluentd 1.6.36
MySQL-Client 5.7.30
MySQL-Server 5.7.30
PHP 7.4.6
Stackdriver-Agent 5.5.2
WP-CLI 2.4.0
WordPress 5.4.1
```

WordPress (Google Click to Deploy)
Estimated costs: $13.61/month

```
Package contents
Apache 2.4.25
Google-Fluentd 1.6.37
MySQL-Client 5.7.30
MySQL-Server 5.7.30
PHP 7.4.7
Stackdriver-Agent 5.5.2
WP-CLI 2.4.0
WordPress 5.4.2
phpMyAdmin 5.0.2
```